Assertion Failed in Boost Statechart When Posting Event in State Constructor
I am using Boost Statechart to create a simple state machine with three states: InitState, ProcessingState, and ExitState. The state machine should transition from InitState to ProcessingState and then to ExitState using custom events. However, when I run the code, I get an assertion failure.
Here is my code:
#include <boost/statechart/event.hpp>
#include <boost/statechart/state_machine.hpp>
#include <boost/statechart/simple_state.hpp>
#include <boost/statechart/transition.hpp>
#include <boost/statechart/custom_reaction.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/list.hpp>
#include <iostream>

namespace state_machine_example {

namespace sc = boost::statechart;

struct InitState;
struct ProcessingState;
struct ExitState;

struct StartProcessing : sc::event<StartProcessing> {};
struct EndProcessing : sc::event<EndProcessing> {};

struct StateMachine : sc::state_machine<StateMachine, InitState> {};

struct InitState : sc::simple_state<InitState, StateMachine> {
    typedef sc::custom_reaction<StartProcessing> reactions;

    InitState() { 
        std::cout << "Entering Init State\n"; 
        this->post_event(StartProcessing());
    }
    ~InitState() { std::cout << "Exiting Init State\n"; }

    sc::result react(const StartProcessing &event) {
        std::cout << "Transitioning from Init to Processing State\n";
        return transit<ProcessingState>();
    }
};

struct ProcessingState : sc::simple_state<ProcessingState, StateMachine> {
    typedef sc::custom_reaction<EndProcessing> reactions;

    ProcessingState() { 
        std::cout << "Entering Processing State\n"; 
        this->post_event(EndProcessing());
    }
    ~ProcessingState() { std::cout << "Exiting Processing State\n"; }

    sc::result react(const EndProcessing &event) {
        std::cout << "Transitioning from Processing to Exit State\n";
        return transit<ExitState>();
    }
};

struct ExitState : sc::simple_state<ExitState, StateMachine> {
    ExitState() { std::cout << "Entering Exit State\n"; }
    ~ExitState() { std::cout << "Exiting Exit State\n"; }
};

}  // namespace state_machine_example

int main() {
    state_machine_example::StateMachine state_machine;
    state_machine.initiate();
    return 0;
}

And here is my terminal output:
Entering Init State
state_machine_main: /usr/include/boost/statechart/simple_state.hpp:459: boost::statechart::simple_state<MostDerived, Context, InnerInitial, historyMode>::outermost_context_base_type& boost::statechart::simple_state<MostDerived, Context, InnerInitial, historyMode>::outermost_context_base() [with MostDerived = state_machine_example::InitState; Context = state_machine_example::StateMachine; InnerInitial = boost::mpl::list<mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na>; boost::statechart::history_mode historyMode = boost::statechart::has_no_history; boost::statechart::simple_state<MostDerived, Context, InnerInitial, historyMode>::outermost_context_base_type = boost::statechart::state_machine<state_machine_example::StateMachine, state_machine_example::InitState>]: Assertion `get_pointer( pContext_ ) != 0' failed.

What causes the assertion failure, and how can I fix it? Is there an issue with posting events from within the state constructor?
Additional Context:

Boost version: 1.74.0
OS: Ubuntu 22.04


Unrelated but you could rewrite all of that in a few lines of code if you used co_yield and let your compiler handle the state machine instead.

I solved the issue. I was going through the source code and found this in simple_state.hpp:
    outermost_context_type & outermost_context()
    {
      // This assert fails when an attempt is made to access the state machine
      // from a constructor of a state that is *not* a subtype of state<>.
      // To correct this, derive from state<> instead of simple_state<>.
      BOOST_ASSERT( get_pointer( pContext_ ) != 0 );
      return pContext_->outermost_context();
    }

I changed my example to use states instead of simple states, like so:
// Init State
struct InitState : sc::state<InitState, StateMachine> {
    typedef sc::custom_reaction<StartProcessing> reactions;

    InitState(my_context ctx) : my_base(ctx) {
        std::cout << "Entering Init State\n";
        // Post the event after construction
        post_event(StartProcessing());
    }
    ~InitState() { std::cout << "Exiting Init State\n"; }

    sc::result react(const StartProcessing &event) {
        std::cout << "Transitioning from Init to Processing State\n";
        return transit<ProcessingState>();
    }
};

And the problem was solved.
